# 404 when passing web api parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm trying to get this method to work:

```
public class DocumentenController : ApiController
{    
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DeleteDocument/{name}/{planId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteDocument(string name, int planId)
    {
      _documentenProvider.DeleteDocument(planId, name);
      return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is the WebApiConfig :

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "ActionApi",
    routeTemplate: UrlPrefix + "/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

But I get a 404 when I call it like this using a post:

```
http://localhost/QS-documenten/api/documenten/deletedocument/testing/10600349
```

What is the proper way do solve this?

Comment: You missed the `RoutePrefix` on the controller level, this makes your route  without the `api/Documenten`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The URL in example does not match attribute route on controller.

To get

```
http://localhost/QS-documenten/api/documenten/deletedocument/testing/10600349
```

to work, assuming that `http://localhost/QS-documenten` is the host and root folder, and that `api/documenten` is the api prefix then add a route prefix to the controller...

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Documenten")]
public class DocumentenController : ApiController {
    //eg POST api/documenten/deletedocument/testing/10600349
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("DeleteDocument/{name}/{planId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteDocument(string name, int planId) {
        _documentenProvider.DeleteDocument(planId, name);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Source: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2 : Route Prefixes](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes)

Answer (score 2):

You must send your request as follows:

```
http://localhost/QS-documenten/deletedocument/testing/10600349
```

When you use route attribute, the custom route override default api routing configuration.